# Представление сцены tableviewCell, не уходит tableFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Как убрать `tableFooterView`? Есть три вида спорта, сделал один вид таблицу - все ушло. Повторил остальные два, обрезается снизу 1/3 экрана закрывает текст.

Вот мой код и скриншот:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = baskets?.detailTitleB

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"BasketballTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "basketCell")
          tableView.reloadData()
          loadMatchBasket()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Что бы убрать футер просто удалити строку с футером. 2) Вы используете AutoLayout? 3) Попробуйте так: tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Comment: Витали , я проверил на форме экрана  айфоне  там все впорядке, не могу  понять почему на айфоне Х  такая фигня.